# Parallelise rfcv from the randomForest package in R

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-selection

I am trying to use the rfcv function to do a multivariate random forest feature selection. I managed to get normal rf command (building the random forest) model to work with parallel processing using the following:

```
library(randomForest)
library(doMC)
nCores <- detectCores();
registerDoMC(nCores) #number of cores on the machine
rf.model <- foreach(ntree=rep(round(510/nCores),nCores), .combine=combine, .multicombine=TRUE, .packages="randomForest") %dopar% {
    rf <- randomForest(y = outcome, x = predictor, ntree=ntree, mtry=4,      norm.votes=FALSE, importance=TRUE)
  }
```

Before using this one i want to use the rfcv for my feature selection. I tried doing it as above with the following:

```
  rf.model <- foreach(1:nCores, .packages="randomForest") %dopar% {
    rf.rfcv <- rfcv(ytrain = outcome, xtrain = predictor, scale=4)
  }
```

However, the outcome of this function is the same replicated for times so i just get rf.rfcv as a list of 4 identical results.

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

randomForest can be run in parallel seamlessly because the randomForest::combine function will reduce 4 rf.objects to one object. So in first code example you train 4 forest models only with the random seed in difference. With, combine=combine (implicit combine=randomForest::combine), you specify the output list of 4 models should be reduced with the specialized combine function from the randomForest package.

rfcv does not have any combine function nor would it be meaningfull to simply combine four outputs. In your code foreach simply runs the function 4 times and returns the outputs in a list. If you like to run rfcv in parallel, a fix would be to something like:

```
my.rfcv = randomForest::rfcv #copy function from package to .Global.env
fix(my.rfcv) #inspect function and perhaps copy entire function to your source functions script

#rewrite for-loop at line 35-57 into a foreach-loop
#write a reducer to combine test results of each fold
```